# Why is the result of this JavaScript duplicated?

Tags: node.js

The result should be 60 but it not, it gives output 20, 40 , 60.

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio"),
urls = [];

for(var pages =1; pages <=3; pages++){
    var target = "http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/"+pages;
   request(target, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $(".listing > header > h2 > a").each(function(){
                var url = this.attribs.href;
                urls.push(url);
            });
            console.log(urls.length);
        }
   });
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing each page has 20 urls, and you are printing total url count for each async call, hence the 20, 40, 60. Use Promise, and print the count after collection of all the urls:

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio"),
urls = [], promises=[], pages, target = "http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/";

function getURLs(pageNo){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     request(target+pageNo, function(error, response, html){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $(".listing > header > h2 > a").each(function(){
          var url = this.attribs.href;
          urls.push(url);
        });
        resolve();
      }else{
        reject(error);
      }
     });
  });
}


for(var pages =1; pages <=3; pages++){
  promises.push(getURLs(pages));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
  console.log(urls.length);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much dude

Answer (score 1):

Your console.log is within your for loop.
Therefore, its going to go to page 1, get 20 results, then output.
Then its going to page 2, and its getting another 20 results, then outputting 40.
Then it goes to page 3, and gets another 20.  then outputs 60.

Place the log outside of the for loop.